# Creating backup server

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud

We have hosted a website on Amazon AWS EC2 server. Now just wanted to know how to create a backup server which will behave like mirror server. It would be two servers running in parallel and if one fails all traffic gets shifted to other server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three aspects to your answer:

- Creating a backup server
- Shared storage between the servers
- Cut-over in case of failure

**Backup Server**

The easiest way to *clone* a server is to create an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) of the existing Amazon EC2 instance. You can then launch additional instances using that AMI, and they will have **exactly the same disk content** at startup (but disk content is separate on each instance, so they will diverge after startup).

**Shared Storage**

This is the most difficult aspect. If your application is read-only, then this is not a problem. However, if your application saves data then you have to consider how that data is available in case of cut-over.

Best practice is **not to store data on the server**, but rather store it on a separate database that is accessible to all instances. This way, if an instance fails, the data is still available to the other instances. (As to backing-up the database, that's a different topic.)

**Cut-over in event of failure**

There are many options available here:

- Use a **Load Balancer** in front of the instances. This will **serve traffic to both instances** all the time (so it's not really cut-over), which makes your application more Highly Available. The Load Balancer can also perform **health checks** and if an instance fails the health check, requests will not be sent to that instance. This method is much better than cut-over because you have the advantage of using multiple instances when they are both healthy, and there is no real "fail-over".
- Use an **Amazon Route 53 health check** on your Primary Amazon EC2 instance. Define a Failover domain name pointing to the Primary server, associated with the health check, plus a Secondary server. If the Primary server fails, Route 53 will send traffic to the Secondary server.

Comment: nice way to explains. Thanks for the answer.